# CEP/JavaScript : How to get the center of a circle?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-extension

I create a circle with this method:

```
var yMinCir = height - 1515.80/2.667+8.5;
var yMaxCir = height - 1545.80/2.667+8.5;
var myCircle = page.ovals.add({geometricBounds:[yMinCir, 1312.63/2.667+8.5, yMaxCir, 1342.63/2.667+8.5]});
```

Is there a way to recover the center by doing for example :

```
var centerOfMyCircle = myCircle.center;
```

Or does it have to be calculated ? If yes, how ?

I searched everywhere but I did not find anything..

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the geometricBounds of the object (the same you are setting). Then the center of your circle will be

```
var gb = myCircle.geometricBounds;
var centery = (gb[2] - gb[0]) / 2;
var centerx = (gb[3] - gb[1]) / 2;
```